# Why can I not run the analyzeSentiment function?

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

I am having an issue running the analyzeSentiment function. I am receiving an error that says:

```
> S1 <- analyzeSentiment(cleanedDoc)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 8.3 Gb
```

Any ideas for a solution to this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: HOw big is the data

Comment: @akrun Dataset is 3 MB

Comment: Can you run it on a subset of data and check if it returns same error

Comment: @akrun Yes, I have run the function before on similar data and it works

Comment: @akrun I also tried using memory.limit(size = 56000) to increase my memory but that did not work

Comment: Sounds like you're going to need to get a computer with more RAM. The error message isn't for the the total amount of RAM required, it's just the last size of memory it tried to allocate.